# upgrade to express4, how to log to console?

Tags: logging, express, migration

I have an express3 app in which I log every http operation to the console like this:

```
app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
```

With express 4 I have to do like this:

```
npm install express-logger --save
```

and then

```
var logger = require('express-logger');
[...]
app.use(logger({path: "/path/to/logfile.txt"}));
```

Is there some way to log to the console like I did with express3?

see: https://github.com/joehewitt/express-logger

Answer (score 0):

I've just read here (https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) that logger is now named morgan.

see: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan